# Substract query from another query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

A simple question that keeps bombing my head.

I have the following two queries:

```
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 3

select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 8
```

And I want to get the result of items that are in warehouse 3 but not in ware 8 and the opposite, those who are in ware 8 and not in ware 3.

The thing is that items may be in both wares I can have the following situation:

```
id_warehouse id_color id_design
---------------------------------
8            RED      STYLISH
3            RED      NEW_AGE
```

So in this situation I would like to retrieve a empty set.

In case that it's just in ware 8 it will return only the first row and the opposite in the ware 3 case.

This can seem easy but I have been all morning with this and no result. I've tried with

```
select * 
from alm_existencias_almacen 
where id_color not in (select * 
                       from alm_existencias_almacen 
                       where id_almacen = 3) 
  and id_design not in (select * 
                        from alm_existencias_almacen 
                        where id_almacen = 3) 
  and id_almacen = 8;
```

But an error occurs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? We can't read your screen - nor your mind - you have to **tell us!** Please post the **exact and complete** error message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use Set Operation [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188055.aspx)

> result of items that are in warehouse 3 but not in ware 8

```
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 3
EXCEPT
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 8
```

> who are in ware 8 and not in ware 3

```
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 8
EXCEPT
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right that this is very easy.

In wh 3 but not in 8, based on id_color:

```
select * from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 3
and id_color not in
    (select id_color from alm_existencias_almacen where id_warehouse = 8)
```